# How can I plot fminsearchbnd function?

Tags: matlab

I want to see on a graph how `uti_pooling` varies wrt `x(2)` which is bounded between `[0.1,1]`.

`plot(x(2),uti_pooling)` brings the graph but without any input.

With `fminsearchbnd` function, I found the `min(max)` of the defined function. But I also want to see how the function varies wrt `x(2)`.

```
pooling = @(x) -0.1*log(10+x(1)*(1-(x(2)+0.1)/2))- 0.9*log(100-x(1)*(x(2)+0.1)/2); %pooling function
[x,fval] = fminsearchbnd(pooling,[0 0],[0 0.1],[1000 1])%min within boundaries
uti_pooling=fval*-1 %converting min to max

plot(x(2),uti_pooling)
```

Comment: Check this [link](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/output-functions.html) it will show you how to plot the evolution of the iteration. Hope that it is also compatible with the custom `fminsearchbnd` function.

Comment: Thank you. It is either not compatible with     'fminsearchbn' or very complicated for me to adapt to my case.

Comment: I suppose you shoud create a map using pool with different input values, plot that with mesh and then display the minimum on top.

Comment: by the way, how come you first upper boundary is -inf?

Comment: (edited) Maybe if I make the input values close to continuity, then it may work. For instance, can I define `x(2)=0.1:1/100:1` ? And how can I run all these `x(2)`s at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is just a dot it is hard to see, try marking it, say with a '.' like this:

```
plot(x(2),uti_pooling,'.')
```

Comment: thank you. However, it partly solves my problem. I also want to see how uti_pooling varies wrt x(2) which is bounded between [0.1,1], i.e. for each value of x(2) within this interval, I'd like to see the max value of my function and plot it in a graph.